# PyCharm and/or python isn't recognizing a WebElement (Selenium) variable until I open the class in the debugger

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am getting some very odd behavior on a project. Essentially this automation creates an article on a web page  using selenium and verifies it's existence by clicking/opening the article. However when i run the program without debug it is failing to "click()" on the web element. So I investigate and start to debug. I notice that the web element ("target_element") is "None". I continue past for just debugging and it fails to click "target_element" as expected.
When i rerun the program and instead of continuing on i open the class in the debug view. I see that "target_element" exists, so i continue on and target_element.click() successfully loads the article on the webpage. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

TLDR; article.target_element does not exist when running the program UNLESS i set a breakpoint and look at "article" in the debugger. Then if i continue in the program article.target_element suddenly exists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Possible reason is the element load time.**

When you are running the test *Selenium* runs faster than the time needed by the element to load properly and eventually throws the exception. On the other hand, during debug you are stepping in and giving enough time for the element to load and *Selenium* finds the element without any issue.

If, the problem is exactly what it is mentioned above the use of [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) should be the way to go.

Example taken from the Selenium Python doc

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I just tried this and i am experiencing the same problem. The element is found on the page and the wait finishes immediately; however the variable is still None unless i explicitly open the class in the debug view. After I view the class then the variable is filled out with the element.

Comment: @Darthlemi Interesting. Can you share your test code?

Comment: I am not able to share anymore code than what i have posted in the picture in the original post

Comment: @Darthlemi I wanted to see how have you implemented the explicit wait. If you have restriction that's fine

Comment: So i changed some things around and added some hardcoded xpaths and the wait you have posted above does work. Now i need to find a way to make this work with my current implementation. Thanks a lot